# Creating a Session Helper Class that uses an array object C#

Tags: c#, arrays, session

I am using a session helper class to track more than several variable. So far I have 30 that are needed from page to page, not all at once of course. I need to convert some of the values from single to array. The Session helper class I use is as follows. For brevity I have shown only two session variables we use for tracking tab index for two accordions.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class SessionHelper
{

    //Session variable constants
    public const string AccordionTop = "#tabTop";
    public const string AccordionBot = "#tabBot";


    public static T Read<T>(string variable)
    {
        object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable];
        if (value == null)
            return default(T);
        else
            return ((T)value);
    }

    public static void Write(string variable, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] = value;
    }

    public static int TabTop
        {
            get
            {
                return Read<int>(AccordionTop);
            }
            set
            {
                Write(AccordionTop, value);
            }
        }

        public static int TabBot
        {
            get
            {
                return Read<int>(AccordionBot);
            }
            set
            {
                Write(AccordionBot, value);
            }
        }
}
```

So on each page I can work with variables easily as follows:

```
To Write:
SessionHelper.TabTop = 1;  or  SessionHelper.TabBot = 3

To Read:
If (SessionHelper.TabTop……….)
```

This all works fine. I now want to extend this to array values held in session. The array contains int, string and date time value.
For the array session object I have tried adding:

```
    public class SessionHelper
    {

       public const string CompInfo = "CompAccInfo";

       public static T ReadArray<T>(string variable)
       {
            object[] result = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] as object[];
            if (result == null)
            {
                return default(T);
                //result = new object[30];
            }
            else
                return ((T)(object)result);
        }

        public static void WriteArray(string variable, object[] value)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] = value;
        }   


public static object[] CompDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return ReadArray<object[]>(CompInfo);
            }
            set
            {
                WriteArray(CompInfo, value);
            }
        }
}
```

But then I get an “Object reference not set to…… error when I try to do this:

```
    public void EGetCompanyInformation(MasterPage myMaster, int entityCode)
        {
            int prevEntity = 0;Using (sqlconnetiooo 
            .....
            //I get values here this works fine
            //Then:
            sqlr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            sqlr.Read();
            if (sqlr.HasRows)
            {
                //Calculate accounting period adjustment.
                yearEndDiff = 12 - Convert.ToInt32(sqlr.GetDateTime(5).Month);

                    //Company Code.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[0] = sqlr.GetInt32(0);
                    //Company Name.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[1] = sqlr.GetString(1);
                    //Currency Unit.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[2] = sqlr.GetString(2);
                    //Base Currency Code.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[3] = sqlr.GetString(3);
                    //Reporting Currency Code.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[4] = sqlr.GetString(4);
                    //Company Year End.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[5] = yearEndDiff;
                    //Country Code.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[6] = sqlr.GetString(6);
                    //Country Name.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[7] = sqlr.GetString(7);
                    //Base Currency Name.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[8] = sqlr.GetString(8);
                    //Report Currency Name.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[9] = sqlr.GetString(9);
                    //ClientID.
                    SessionHelper.CompDetails[10] = sqlr.GetInt32(10);
Other code here
}

}
```

It seems any  SessionHelper.CompDetails[i] does not work : Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default(object[])` will always throw `null`. because the array of object is reference type and default value of any reference type is null. So accessing null value will get you `Object reference not set to an instance of object`.

You can change your old implementation like below:

```
public static T Read<T>(string variable, int arraySize=10)
{
    object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable];
    if(typeof(T).IsArray && value == null)
    {
      //array requires size I personally prefer to have
      //differnt read method for array.
      return ((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),arraySize));
    }
    if(!typeof(T).IsValueType && value == null)
    {
        //if it is not value type you can return new instance.
        return ((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));
    }        
    else if (value == null)
        return default(T);
    else
        return ((T)value);
}
```

And access SessionHelper as below:

```
var sessionarray = SessionHelper.Read<object[]>("myarray",15);
....
// then use that sessionarray here.
....
```

Comment: Hi Jenish: This is the implementation I am looking for. However , I can't get past  the line "return Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(T));"  I am getting an error "An instrance of type 'object' cannot be returned by a method of type 'T'. I have tried type conversion (T)(object) that worked in my old version by no joy in this implementation. Can you help me resolve this.?

Comment: I get System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. at the sam e line....

Comment: @Jinesh. Yes I worked that out yesterday. Used 
        public static T ReadArray<T>(string variable, int selected, int arrayLen)
        {
            object[] value = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] as object[];
            if (!typeof(T).IsValueType && value == null)
            {                
              since I had another parameter to re-use method for other arrays. Thanks so much for your help. This is the exact implementation I was looking for. Your last post confirms we have the correct implementation. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if `ReadArray` will return default(T)? It will return null. Than access to any object by index inside the array will cause the exception you face.

It is not quite obvious what your code is intended to do.

```
SessionHelper.CompDetails[0] = sqlr.GetInt32(0);
```

What do you want here? CompDetails itself should return an array. But you are trying to rewrite it immediately by some values.

If you want to access the CompDetails and rewrite it's objects than you have to instantiate it by

```
int n = 10;
SessionHelper.CompDetails = new CompDetails[n];
```

Comment: SessionHelper.CompDetails[0] = sqlr.GetInt32(0);

Comment: This is not a problem, It works fine by getting the company code stored in a sql databases and writes is to the array at index0 . the array contains other details extracted like company name at position 1 etc. I am looking for changes needed to the public static T Read<T>(string variable) to instantiate CompDetails when first accessed not SessionHelper.CompDetails = new CompDetails[n];

Comment: The part I was looking for is answered below by "influxed" and I am testing its implementation now       ........p.e        if(!typeof(T).IsValueType && value == null)
    {
        //if it is not value type you can return new instance.
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the CompDetails array before you start assigning values to it.

```
if (sqlr.HasRows)
{
    //Calculate accounting period adjustment.
    yearEndDiff = 12 - Convert.ToInt32(sqlr.GetDateTime(5).Month);

    // Instantiate array
    SessionHelper.CompDetails = new object[11];

    //Company Code.
    SessionHelper.CompDetails[0] = sqlr.GetInt32(0);

    // etc
```